# Sphinx - attribute not found

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm trying to get all posiblle responses, but so far only result what I'm getting is:

> index test_responses: group-by attribute 'rr' not found

Here is sphinx.conf:

```
source test_responses {
    type = mysql
    sql_host = ******
    sql_user = ******
    sql_pass = ******
    sql_db = ******
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8

    sql_query = \
        SELECT responseID, respondentID, response, \
            questionID, surveyID, response as rr \
        FROM responses WHERE deleted IS NULL
    sql_attr_string = rr
    sql_attr_uint = questionID
    sql_query_info = SELECT * from responses where responseID = $id
}

index test_responses {
    source = test_responses
    path = /var/run/sphinxsearch
    charset_type = utf-8
}
```

And PHP code:

```
$query_string = "";
$index_name = "test_responses";
$sphinx_client = new SphinxClient();
$sphinx_client->SetServer(SPHINX_HOSTNAME, 3312); 
$sphinx_client->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$sphinx_client->setLimits(0, 0);

$sphinx_client->SetFilter("questionID", 604);
$sphinx_client->SetGroupBy("rr", SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR);
$result = $sphinx_client->Query($query_string, $index_name);
```

Why this is happen to me??? ;}

Comment: Did you rebuild your index after changing the config file?

Comment: absoluty: indexer --all --rotate

Comment: What version of sphinx do you have? As noted in the help page linked in Moosh's answer, only available since 2.0.1-beta

Answer (score 0):

regarding http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.7/conf-sql-attr-string.html

sql_attr_string = title # will be stored but will not be indexed

try sql_attr_str2ordinal = rr

Comment: It wont be full-text indexed. But sql_attr_string, SHOULD work for grouping. Read the documentation page you linked to!